# After updating to Magento 2.3.2 checkout page throws error

Tags: onestepcheckout, magento2.3.2, knockout

After I update Magento version from 2.3.0 to 2.3.2 on checkout page I got knockout errors on my console and payments, product items do not show on-page. Before update, it works well.

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "visible: function(){return isVisible() }"
Message: isVisible is not defined
    at visible (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2992), <anonymous>:3:60)
    at update (knockout.js:4971)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3383)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2183)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2150)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2111)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1964)
    at knockout.js:3381
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:159)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3353)
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return detailsTemplate }"
Message: detailsTemplate is not defined
    at template (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2992), <anonymous>:3:61)
    at init (knockout.js:5464)
    at knockout.js:3368
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1480)
    at knockout.js:3367
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:159)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3353)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:3233)
    at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:3215)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:3242)
```

Comment: Are you using vanilla magento checkout? Or one step checkout extension?

Comment: @DominicXigen onestep

Comment: Hi if it is a commercial extension bought by 3rd party vendor then support can usually solve such issues. Your issue indicates that maybe your static assets are still from old version of Magento , clear all caches out (manually if needed) and try again.

Comment: Hi, did you finally solve this issue I have the same issue using the default Magento checkout ?

Comment: @magentodev hello, partially fixed. I replaced knockout parts from 2.3.0 and insert 2.3.2. It's partially fixed this issue, and I don't have an error, but still, troubles in front-end elements rendering (because of the custom template). So, replacing knockout js files may help you.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll test !

Comment: I have same issue. I was tried use base theme. but still not working